# ¿Como habilitar el test de web service (invoke button) en IIS desde un server remoto?

Tags: webservice, iis, test

Necesito probar/invocar un webservice montado en IIS desde otro server. El boton de invocar y los campos a completar aparecen solo desde localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Para habilitar la página de prueba del servicio web remoto (invoke button), simplemente agregue el protocolo HttpPost / HttpGet en la sección webServices de su web.config

```
<webServices>
     <protocols>
       <add name="HttpGet"/>
       <add name="HttpPost"/>
     </protocols>
</webServices>
```

[fuente: codeproject.com](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/146329/How-to-enable-the-remote-test-page-invoke-button-f)